# Values of variable changes when trying to use drop_na() function

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a problem with removing NA values from my dataset, because for some reason a variable starts changing values then. I have the following df (I simplified it a bit, otherwise it would be way to long, hopefully it is better like this):

```
data.frame(
       stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
              fkeycompany = c("0000001961","0000001961","0000001961","0000001961",
                              "0000001961","0000001961","0000001961",
                              "0000001961","0000001961","0000001961",
                              "0000001961","0000001961","0000001961",
                              "0000001961","0000001961","0000001961","0000001961",
                              "0000001961","0000001961","0000002969",
                              "0000002969","0000002969","0000002969",
                              "0000002969","0000002969","0000002969","0000002969",
                              "0000002969","0000002969","0000002969",
                              "0000002969","0000002969","0000002969",
                              "0000002969","0000002969","0000002969",
                              "0000002969","0000002969","0000003570","0000003570",
                              "0000003570","0000003570","0000003570",
                              "0000003570","0000003570","0000003570",
                              "0000003570","0000003570","0000003570","0000003570",
                              "0000003570","0000003570","0000003570",
                              "0000003570","0000003570","0000003570",
                              "0000003570","0000003570","0000003570",
                              "0000004187","0000004187","0000004187","0000004187",
                              "0000004187","0000004187","0000004187",
                              "0000004187","0000004187","0000004187",
                              "0000004187","0000004187","0000004187","0000004187",
                              "0000004187","0000004187","0000006885",
                              "0000006885","0000006885","0000006885",
                              "0000006885","0000006885","0000006885",
                              "0000006885","0000006885","0000006885","0000006885",
                              "0000006885","0000006885","0000006885",
                              "0000006885","0000006885","0000006885",
                              "0000008855","0000008855","0000008855","0000008855",
                              "0000008855","0000008855","0000008855",
                              "0000008855"),
               fiscalyear = c(2000,
                              2001,2001,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,
                              2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,
                              2019,2020,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,
                              2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,
                              2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2002,2002,
                              2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2007,2008,
                              2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,
                              2017,2018,2019,2020,2005,2005,2006,2006,
                              2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,
                              2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2002,2003,2004,
                              2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,
                              2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2004,
                              2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011),
            fiscalyearend = c("2000-12-31","2001-12-31","2001-12-31","2005-12-31",
                              "2006-12-31","2007-12-31","2008-12-31",
                              "2009-12-31","2010-12-31","2011-12-31",
                              "2012-12-31","2013-12-31","2014-12-31",
                              "2015-12-31","2016-12-31","2017-12-31","2018-12-31",
                              "2019-12-31","2020-12-31","2002-09-30",
                              "2003-09-30","2004-09-30","2005-09-30",
                              "2006-09-30","2007-09-30","2008-09-30","2009-09-30",
                              "2010-09-30","2011-09-30","2012-09-30",
                              "2013-09-30","2014-09-30","2015-09-30",
                              "2016-09-30","2017-09-30","2018-09-30",
                              "2019-09-30","2020-09-30","2002-12-31","2002-12-31",
                              "2003-12-31","2004-12-31","2005-12-31",
                              "2006-12-31","2007-12-31","2007-12-31",
                              "2008-12-31","2009-12-31","2010-12-31","2011-12-31",
                              "2012-12-31","2013-12-31","2014-12-31",
                              "2015-12-31","2016-12-31","2017-12-31",
                              "2018-12-31","2019-12-31","2020-12-31",
                              "2005-12-31","2005-12-31","2006-12-31","2006-12-31",
                              "2007-12-31","2008-12-31","2009-12-31",
                              "2010-12-31","2011-12-31","2012-12-31",
                              "2013-12-31","2014-12-31","2015-12-31","2016-12-31",
                              "2017-12-31","2018-12-31","2003-01-31",
                              "2004-01-31","2005-01-31","2006-01-31",
                              "2007-01-31","2008-01-31","2009-01-31",
                              "2010-01-31","2011-01-31","2012-01-31","2013-01-31",
                              "2014-01-31","2015-01-31","2016-01-31",
                              "2017-01-31","2018-01-31","2019-01-31",
                              "2004-12-31","2005-12-31","2006-12-31","2007-12-31",
                              "2008-12-31","2009-12-31","2010-12-31",
                              "2011-12-31"),
              namecompany = c("WORLDS INC","WORLDS INC","WORLDS INC","WORLDS INC",
                              "WORLDS INC","WORLDS INC","WORLDS INC",
                              "WORLDS INC","WORLDS INC","WORLDS INC",
                              "WORLDS INC","WORLDS INC","WORLDS INC",
                              "WORLDS INC","WORLDS INC","WORLDS INC","WORLDS INC",
                              "WORLDS INC","WORLDS INC",
                              "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC","AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC",
                              "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC",
                              "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC",
                              "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC","AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC",
                              "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC",
                              "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC","AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC",
                              "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC",
                              "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC","AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC",
                              "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC",
                              "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC","AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC",
                              "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC",
                              "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC",
                              "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC","AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC",
                              "CHENIERE ENERGY INC","CHENIERE ENERGY INC",
                              "CHENIERE ENERGY INC","CHENIERE ENERGY INC",
                              "CHENIERE ENERGY INC","CHENIERE ENERGY INC",
                              "CHENIERE ENERGY INC","CHENIERE ENERGY INC",
                              "CHENIERE ENERGY INC","CHENIERE ENERGY INC",
                              "CHENIERE ENERGY INC","CHENIERE ENERGY INC",
                              "CHENIERE ENERGY INC","CHENIERE ENERGY INC",
                              "CHENIERE ENERGY INC","CHENIERE ENERGY INC",
                              "CHENIERE ENERGY INC","CHENIERE ENERGY INC",
                              "CHENIERE ENERGY INC","CHENIERE ENERGY INC",
                              "CHENIERE ENERGY INC","INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC",
                              "INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC",
                              "INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC",
                              "INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC","INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC",
                              "INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC",
                              "INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC","INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC",
                              "INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC",
                              "INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC","INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC",
                              "INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC",
                              "INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC","INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC",
                              "INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC",
                              "INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC","STAGE STORES INC",
                              "STAGE STORES INC","STAGE STORES INC",
                              "STAGE STORES INC","STAGE STORES INC","STAGE STORES INC",
                              "STAGE STORES INC","STAGE STORES INC",
                              "STAGE STORES INC","STAGE STORES INC",
                              "STAGE STORES INC","STAGE STORES INC",
                              "STAGE STORES INC","STAGE STORES INC","STAGE STORES INC",
                              "STAGE STORES INC","STAGE STORES INC",
                              "AMERICAN LOCKER GROUP INC",
                              "AMERICAN LOCKER GROUP INC","AMERICAN LOCKER GROUP INC",
                              "AMERICAN LOCKER GROUP INC","AMERICAN LOCKER GROUP INC",
                              "AMERICAN LOCKER GROUP INC",
                              "AMERICAN LOCKER GROUP INC","AMERICAN LOCKER GROUP INC"),
                    lloss = c("1","1",
                              "1","0","1","0","1","1","1","1","1",
                              "1","1","1","1","1","0","1","1","0",
                              "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                              "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1",
                              "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                              "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0",
                              "0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                              "0","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                              "0","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0",
                              "0","0","0","0","1","1","1","0","1",
                              "0","1","1","1","0","0"),
            going_concern = c(1,1,1,
                              1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,
                              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                              0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,
                              0,0,0,0,0),
                     big4 = c("0","0",
                              "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                              "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","1",
                              "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                              "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0",
                              "0","0","0","0","0","1","1","1","1",
                              "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                              "1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                              "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                              "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1","1",
                              "1","1","1","1","1","1","1","0","0",
                              "0","0","0","0","0","0"),
                   tenure = c(1,1,1,
                              2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,1,2,3,1,2,
                              3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,
                              14,15,16,17,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,1,1,
                              2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,1,
                              2,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,2,3,
                              4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,
                              17,18,1,1,2,3,4,1,2,3),
                  tenure2 = c(1,1,1,
                              1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,
                              1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                              0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,
                              0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
                              1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
                              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,
                              0,0,1,1,0),
                reportlag = c(89,2201,
                              2201,740,375,57,100,97,48,104,102,91,
                              105,102,107,92,59,90,75,28,24,27,
                              53,73,58,56,56,54,53,51,57,55,55,52,
                              47,51,57,50,66,66,60,69,69,58,57,
                              57,57,56,61,55,53,52,50,49,55,51,56,
                              55,54,44,44,78,78,87,90,78,87,67,
                              91,90,105,85,90,85,72,37,37,66,88,72,
                              59,55,58,59,60,60,60,60,60,60,65,
                              66,77,607,242,168,397,90,74,75),
going_concern_old_opinion = c(1,1,1,
                              NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,
                              NA,1,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                              NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,1,
                              1,NA,0,NA,0,0,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                              0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,NA,NA,NA,
                              NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,
                              NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                              NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,1,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA),
going_concern_new_opinion = c(1,1,1,
                              NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,
                              NA,0,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                              NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,0,
                              0,NA,0,NA,0,0,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                              0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,NA,NA,NA,
                              NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,
                              NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,
                              NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,0,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA)
```

However, I want to remove all the values from the going_concern_new_opinion variable. When i am doing this, the tenure and tenure2 variable changes as well (tenure2 variable is logical, as it referres to the tenure variable, using a case_when function). So when i use this function:

```
df <- df %>% drop_na(going_concern_new_opinion)
```

It starts looking like this:

```
data.frame(
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                fkeycompany = c("0000001961",
                                "0000001961","0000001961","0000001961",
                                "0000001961","0000002969","0000002969",
                                "0000003570","0000003570","0000003570","0000003570",
                                "0000003570","0000003570","0000003570",
                                "0000004187","0000004187","0000004187","0000004187",
                                "0000008855","0000008855","0000008855"),
                 fiscalyear = c(2000,2001,
                                2001,2015,2018,2002,2019,2002,2002,2004,
                                2006,2007,2007,2014,2005,2005,2009,2017,
                                2004,2005,2009),
              fiscalyearend = c("2000-12-31",
                                "2001-12-31","2001-12-31","2015-12-31",
                                "2018-12-31","2002-09-30","2019-09-30",
                                "2002-12-31","2002-12-31","2004-12-31","2006-12-31",
                                "2007-12-31","2007-12-31","2014-12-31",
                                "2005-12-31","2005-12-31","2009-12-31","2017-12-31",
                                "2004-12-31","2005-12-31","2009-12-31"),
                namecompany = c("WORLDS INC",
                                "WORLDS INC","WORLDS INC","WORLDS INC",
                                "WORLDS INC","AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC",
                                "AIR PRODUCTS & CHEMICALS INC","CHENIERE ENERGY INC",
                                "CHENIERE ENERGY INC","CHENIERE ENERGY INC",
                                "CHENIERE ENERGY INC","CHENIERE ENERGY INC",
                                "CHENIERE ENERGY INC","CHENIERE ENERGY INC",
                                "INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC",
                                "INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC","INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC",
                                "INDUSTRIAL SERVICES AMER INC",
                                "AMERICAN LOCKER GROUP INC","AMERICAN LOCKER GROUP INC",
                                "AMERICAN LOCKER GROUP INC"),
                      lloss = c("1","1","1",
                                "1","0","0","0","1","1","1","1","1",
                                "1","1","0","0","0","1","0","1","1"),
              going_concern = c(1,1,1,1,0,
                                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
                       big4 = c("0","0","0",
                                "0","0","1","1","0","0","0","0","1",
                                "1","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
                     tenure = c(1,1,1,1,1,
                                1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                    tenure2 = c(1,1,1,1,1,
                                1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
                  reportlag = c(89,2201,
                                2201,102,59,28,57,66,66,69,58,57,57,50,
                                44,44,78,85,77,607,90),
  going_concern_old_opinion = c(1,1,1,1,1,
                                0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0),
  going_concern_new_opinion = c(1,1,1,1,0,
                                0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0))
```

The tenure variable changes all values to 1, instead of their original values. I would like it to stay on their original values. How can i fix this? Is there any way that i can fix the values from the tenure column so it can't change?

Comment: In the first data frame you share, you have `tenure2 = c(1,1,1,
                              1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,
                              1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
                              0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,
                              0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,
                              1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,
                              0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,
                              0,0,1,1,0)`. It is evidently not logical, it is integer to begin with, so there is no change, as expected.

Comment: In my original dataset, the class function gives integer for tenure and numeric for tenure2. Using typeof gives integer for tenure and double for tenure2. Tenure2 is calculated by using case_when, and for tenure < 3 it gives value 1, otherwise 0. What should i change? Convert it to a different type of class?

Comment: The only code you show is `drop_na`. That shouldn't change the column classes. We can do a simple test to demonstrate it behaves as expected: `data.frame(x = c(1, 0, NA), y = c(T, F, T)) %>% drop_na` works fine. So you should rerun your code one line at a time and isolate which one actually changes from boolean on double. Post a little bit of data right before that step while the column is still a boolean (just a few rows, just necessary columns--we don't need 20+ rows and 10+ columns). You can use `dput()` to generate shareable data, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:10, c(1, 3, 4)])`